# Passing initial data from the server into React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, httpresponse, server-side-rendering

I'm building a static Q&A web site that renders all its pages server-side via Django, with the exception of one page which is rendered client-side using React (the View Question page). There is a `questionId` that my React application needs to know in order to make the initial Ajax request to fetch the question data to populate the page.

**What is the best way to embed a value in the server response so that React can read it upon initialization?**

A few solutions I can think of (neither of these seem very elegant):

1. Add a `data-question-id` attribute to some tag in the page; populate this when the page is rendered server-side, then read it from React.
2. Parse the value from the URL `/question/question-id-value/` from within React.

*(Note: I am **not** asking how to make an asynchronous request to the server)*

Answer (score 2):

I'd use ReactRouter to pass information from the route (URL) to the application.
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md

Answer (score -2):

You can use global javascript variable like

```
DataExchanger = {
   questionId: x
}
```